# Salesforce OAuth Token via API Request

Tags: python, salesforce

I am new to the salesforce API. Currently I am working on a helper method that would allow us to create a new user in our salesforce sandbox. 
One stumbling block I have hit at the moment is how to get an auth token from salesforce so I can pass that along with my other requests.

Here is the code [python] I have thus far:

```
def get_sf_auth_token(username, password):
req_username = 'users_name_here'
req_password = 'users_password_here'
req_url = 'https://na3.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'

payload = {"client_id":"COMNSUMER_KEY",
           "client_secret":"CONSUMER_SECRET",
           "username": req_username,
           "password": req_password
           }

sf_token = requests.post(req_url, data=payload)
print(sf_token.status_code)
print(sf_token.text)
```

Two values I am missing are CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET. I do not know where these values come from.

When I send this request I get back the following:

```
400
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
```

what is a grant type?

In general I just need help with this, any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add the `grant_type` to your `payload`. The value for the `grant_type` key should be `password` since you're using the username and password auth flow.

```
payload = {"client_id":"COMNSUMER_KEY",
           "client_secret":"CONSUMER_SECRET",
           "username": req_username,
           "password": req_password,
           "grant_type": "password" 
           }
```

You'll also want to be sure you append the security token to the end of the password in the payload. More info on this can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm).

To get the `client_id` and `client_secret`, you need to create a connected app in the Salesforce UI. The steps for this process can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205876&type=1).

Comment: Thanks very much I'll have a look.

Comment: If you find this answer helps you @Lombax don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Simple-Salesforce python package, it does not require a consumer key. You just use your email address, password and security token.

```
from simple_salesforce import SFType
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce 
sf = Salesforce(username='my_Salesforce_Email@mail.com', password='my_SF_password', security_token='my_Generated_token_from_Salesforce', client_id='This does not really matter')
```

Then a create would look like:

```
sf.Contact.create({'FirstName' : First, 'LastName' : Last, 'Newsletter__c' : Newsletter, 'Email' : Email1, 'Phone' : Phone, 'MailingStreet' : Street+" "+Apt, 'MailingCity' : City, 'MailingPostalCode' : Postal, 'AccountId' : "001U000001ZEB89"})
```